# How to speed up wait wake-up from notify_all?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Platform: Python 2.6 on CentOS 6

I've got 2 threads using the same object. Thread 1 feeds the object data and when the correct data is found, it does a `threading.Condition.notify_all()`.

Thread 2, via the object, calls `threading.Condition.wait()` on the same condition variable.

I'm grabbing `datetime.datetime.now()` before the `notify_all()` call, and after the `wait()` call. The time difference between the two varies between 9 and 45 ms. That's an eternity!

What I've tried: I've called `os.nice()` to decrease the priority of Thread1, hoping that it would force an immediate context switch [ I call `os.nice()` inside Thread 1's `threading.Thread()` target ]. No love. Also no love by adding a `time.sleep(0.001)` after the call to `notify_all()`.

I should also note this is a multi-process application, these 2 threads are in one of about 5 processes. I'm running on a Xeon with 8 hyper-threaded cores and 32 GB of RAM. So the processor pipe should be phenomenal.

Suggestions? Questions that I need to be asking that I may not have asked myself yet?  I expect some context-switching time, but 45 ms seems absolutely ludicrous. It truly is an eternity.

EDIT:  the code that uses the condition variable.

```
def ProcessEvent( self, event ):
    with self.__conditionVar:
        if self.__testEvent( event ):
            self.__notifyTime = datetime.now()
            self.__conditionVar.notify_all()

def WaitForEvent( self, timeout_sec ):
    with self.__conditionVar:
        if not self.__alreadyFound():
            self.__conditionVar.wait( timeout_sec )
            delta = datetime.now() - self.__notifyTime
            print "Wake-up time =", delta
```

Comment: It's not context switching time. It's time for the first thread to finish with the object. The whole point of the lock is to prevent two threads from accessing the thread at the same time. They have to take turns.

Answer (score 0):

To speed the wake up from `notify_all`, hold the lock for less time after `wait` returns. It's the lock that's preventing the other thread from making progress.

If this doesn't make the solution to your problem obvious, there's a very good chance that you are misusing conditions. If so, explain why you are using conditions.

Comment: I added the code from the 2 function calls. As soon as I `notify_all()` I let go of the lock.

Comment: @PfunnyGuy You misread me. I said to "hold the lock for less time *after wait returns*".

Comment: I'm going to have read about CV's again. I thought the lock was getting returned as soon as the `wait()` returned, because it exited the `with` block.  That'll be my #1 to-do after a night's sleep.

Comment: @PfunnyGuy If you are trying to micro-optimize, you should do absolutely nothing while holding the lock that can be done without holding the lock. Your `print` is done while holding the lock. Print is not only heavy, but also requires synchronization because the output channel is a shared resource.

Comment: @David_Schwartz: Thanks. I am returning the delta instead of printing it immediately, printing it only after my time critical stuff occurs. It helps some, but still the numbers I'm looking at from `notify_all()` to `wait()` wake up is between 4 and 39 ms.  Sadly I've not had more than 15 minutes just now to see if you responded and try that, and I'm off to the next thing. I'll need to research to make sure that CV is the best alternative.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @PfunnyGuy So that halved the best case wakeup (which should be the one you care about). Likely existing overhead in the language arranging to run the thread is comparable in cost to the output function.